# Is there a way to make my local AppCmd.exe to refer to a remote server?

Tags: iis, iis-7, appcmd

I need to remotely administrate IIS via command-line. Is there a way to make my local `AppCmd.exe` refer to a remote server? So that every command I pass to `AppCmd.exe` would be executed in another machine?

Answer (score 6):

You can download [PSEXEC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and run the following command:

```
psexec \\servername c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd
```

For example

```
psexec \\servername c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wp
```

Comment: Be aware that doing this could set off major alarms in your organization if you are in a company that watches for stuff like this.

Comment: Please don't forget about [PsExec gets stuck on licence prompt when running non-interactively](https://serverfault.com/questions/274831/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-local-appcmd-exe-to-refer-to-a-remote-server/703881#703881) and use the `PsExec /accepteula` switch for your invocations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly use `appcmd` for remote management. But IIS 7 has a PowerShell provider for remote management, check [this article](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/04/14/iis-7-0-powershell-provider-tech-preview-1.aspx).

Comment: I've been banging my head against the walls for weeks on this thing, so a heads-up: the IIS Powershell providers for remote management are *awful* if you use UNC shares for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you're using Shared Configuration, but I don't think that's your intent.

Otherwise it's PSEXEC, remote Powershell, or similar.